# Windows для x86 и ARM?

Tags: windows, mac, x86

Объясните пожалуйста, вот Windows написано под процессоры архитектуры x86. Вроде, как говорят написана на Си.
Вот есть такое явление, как МакБуки, которые теперь работают на процессорах архитектуры ARM.

В чем проблема у Microsoft сделать Windows под Mac ? Ведь если Windows написана на Си, в чем проблема это все портировать на ARM, ведь компиляторы Си существуют так же и для них ?

Comment: Проблемы портировать нет, так как все уже портировано: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/apps-on-arm Это на 100% вопрос к производителям железа, предоставляют ли они драйвера для Windows ARM, и поддерживают ли официально ее установку на свои устройства.

Comment: ну вот даже в [википедийной страничке](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows) перечислены поддерживаемые «платформы»: ARM, IA-64, Itanium, MIPS, DEC Alpha, PowerPC и x86. можно ж было заглянуть и прочитать, прежде чем задумываться о том, существует ли некоторая проблема на самом деле.

Comment: aleksandr barakin, виноват. Я почему то был уверен, что это не так и даже гуглить не стал.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight `Это на 100% вопрос к производителям железа, предоставляют ли они драйвера для Windows ARM, и поддерживают ли официально ее установку на свои устройства.` — надо думать, основная проблема нераспространённости сборок ms/windows на архитектурах отличных от интеловской — отсутствие программ, способных работать на этих архитектурах. ведь в состав операционной системы ms/windows не входит даже компилятор. а подавляющее большинство (популярных) программ — проприетарные, исходники отсутствуют в публичном доступе, кроме владельца никто сборку под новую архитектуру не сделает.

Comment: так что опора на проприетарное п.о. (со стороны ms) — это и тот камень на шее у ms/windows, который не даёт ей «всплыть» со дна когда-то выбранной интеловской архитектуры.

Comment: aleksandr barakin, но, если Windows запускается на Mac`е то API же у нее то же? Если да, то почему уже написанное ПО не пойдет ?

Comment: кхм. и при чём тут торговая марка mac, под которой выпускаются компьютеры с несколькими вариантами процессорных архитектур? вы что, не понимаете, чем архитектура процессоров arm отличается от архитектуры, например, интеловских процессоров? // да, есть, конечно, эмуляторы/виртуализаторы. но это ж накладные расходы. как говорится, «в доте фпс упадёт ниже плинтуса». // p.s. чтобы собеседник получил уведомление, надо его явно упомянуть. например, так: `@aleksandr`

Comment: @aleksandr barakin, я почему то думал, что ОС должна скрывать архитектуру. Ну условно вызов функции wprintf() для программиста будет одинаков если он пишет по Windows без разницы архитектуры.

Comment: программист-то напишет. и даже скомпилирует — под набор команд интеловского процессора. а владелец будет продавать этот блоб. который будет работать (без эмуляции/виртуализации) только на компьютерах с интеловским процессором. и к чему владельцу тратиться на расширение штата (как минимум отдела тестирования), ради того, чтобы эти наёмные работники поддерживали и сборки для иных процессорных архитектур? разве окупятся эти расходы, с учётом мизерного количества пользователей ms/windows на компьютерах с архитектурой, отличной от интеловской?

Comment: @Optimus1, если бы код ОС windows (вместе с кодом популярной прикладухи) был бы также доступен и также поддерживался сообществом, как код linux, то желающие запустить его на компах с arm-ом нашлись бы

Comment: @Optimus1 Windows ARM содержит эмулятор x86, поэтому существующие приложения можно запустить. То что вы хотите, полная отвязка от архитектуры, реализуется с помощью компиляции в байткод (Java, .NET).